# Why does my react app receive ...has been blocked by CORS policy from c' api

Tags: c#, reactjs, cors, .net-6.0, fetch-api

I have a react 18 create-react-app hosted on an azure vm.

I have .NET 6 minimal api hosted on a physical server of the same domain.

The react app sends a fetch-api POST request to the c# api. There are no proxies or other cors configuration on my react app.

If I add these two configs to the start of my api

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod() .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "https://myCorrect.domain.co.uk");  
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

I can run this fine with localhost when i host both of these projects locally.
However, I get a cors issue when both of them are deployed in prod.

I receive this in the console of Firefox(similar error on Chrome)

> ...has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
> doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
> header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response
> serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the
> resource with CORS disabled.

Now if I change my api settings to

```
builder.Services.AddCors();

 app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin 
        .AllowCredentials());
```

The react app's request is successfully received on the api.

I would like to know how I can make it work with the first approach, as the second one seems to be bypassing the point of cors.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Never allow all origins with credentials! Doing so is very insecure.

Comment: Yes, I am aware, however I cannot make it work with the first approach. That's why I'm asking what's wrong with the first approach that I'm using.